# Appending rows to tables with prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

How do I append a row to a table using the prototype library.

This is part of a form so I would like to also find a way to increment the <input name="container[0]"> value. Is this possible?

Comment: oh it chopped out my html. I want to increment the name="inputname[0]" portion of an input tag within the row.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if i understand you right something like this would work:

```
var numrows = $$('#tableid tr').length;
$('tableRow').insert({after:'<tr><td><input type="text" name="container['+numrows+']"></td></tr>'});
```

if you can provide more details then i'll be able to help out a bit more